# What is the use of "else" after "for" loop in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

It seems both of the below codes are printing the same, then what is the need of "else" block after "for" loop in python.

Code 1:

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
else:
    print "after for loop"
```

Code 2:

```
for i in range(10):
    print i

print "after for loop"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

> Loop statements may have an `else` clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with `for`) or when the condition becomes false (with `while`), but not when the loop is terminated by a `break` statement.

Follow the link for an example how this can be used.

Answer (score 4):

`else` executes after `for` providing `for` *wasn't terminated with `break`*:

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
    if i == 8:
        break # termination, no else    
else:
    print "after for loop"
```

Comment: What happens when the range is empty (i.e. when the loop body isn't executed at all)?

Comment: @AaronDigulla Then the `break` cannot be reached. So the loop acts as if there was no `break, `going to `else`.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: "else" will be executed since "for" is not interrupted

Answer (score 1):

This was originally enacted in order to get rid of all the "GOTO" statements in procedures without using flags:
It means "NO BREAK"

```
for i, value in enumerate(sequence):
    if value == target:
        break
else:           #<-- if we finish the loop and did not encounter break, return -1
    return -1
return 1        #<-- if we did encounter break, return 1
```

You can watch Raymond Hettinger's Pycon talk that mentions the for/else construct here: [Transforming Code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python](http://pyvideo.org/video/1780/transforming-code-into-beautiful-idiomatic-pytho)