# Python - Program to check whether a number is prime or not

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I just tried to write a basic program (to check whether a number is prime or not). I referred the code from an online site and tried to write one myself.

The code is as follows:

```
#PYTHON PROGRAM TO CHECK PRIME NUMBER
print("Enter a number :: ", end = " ")
num = int(input())

if num > 1:
    for i in range(2,int(num/2)):
        if(num%i) == 0:
            print(str(num) + " is not prime")
            break;
    else:
        print(str(num) + " is prime")

else:
    print(str(num) + " is neither prime nor composite.")
```

The doubt I have is in the working of the code. It runs without any errors and produces the correct output as well.

The confusing code snippet is:

```
for i in range(2,int(num/2)):
    if(num%i) == 0:
        print(str(num) + " is not prime")
        break;
else:
    print(str(num) + " is prime")
```

EDIT:
Why is there an else after the for loop and not after the if statement?
Could someone please explain?

Comment: Which part of that don't you understand? Do you know what `%` does?

Comment: it is typical `for...else` construct. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625189/what-is-the-use-of-else-after-for-loop-in-python

Comment: @mad_ Yes, that was my doubt. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this for loop checks all numbers contained from 2 to the half of the input number. If any numbers along the way yield a perfect division with no remainder (ex. 4%2 = 0) then it breaks. The % operator gives you the remainder of an int division (ex. 5%2 = 1). Hence for a prime number there should always be a remainder, since no perfect division should be possible in the specified range. If there is no remainder then the code breaks the loop and classifies this number as not prime.

Comment: I think OP understands the logic. `for..else` is the part which is confusing to OP and many others.